# Preserve Search engine index while shifting to new Domain

Tags: plugins, seo, redirect

We are in process to migrate old old domain to new domain using wordpress. this migration is happening on the same server and IP (need to confirm but still 99% sure).
I have already asked same question few time back on pro-webmaster [preserve-search-engine-index-while-shifting-to-new-domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21720/preserve-search-engine-index-while-shifting-to-new-domain).
Since the database is same, all we did is export the data from old database to new database changed the link and now everything is perfect.

i know about that we can set 301 redirect in the .htacces file but not sure how to do this, and since there are so many links in the old domain.
i am not sure how best we can handle this redirect. Do we need to create a mapping for each old URL to new URL?
and where we should put these mapping in the Old domain?
any help in this regard will be much helpful.If i need to provide more information, please let me know i will put any other required information in  post.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/), you can just setup a regex redirect from `(www.)?olddomain.com` to `www.newdomain.com` (you should be using www., it's better for SEO as it helps page load time. and that single rule should pretty much do it for you.

You can do this same thing in .htaccess, and it would be more efficient, but I couldn't tell if you had the capability for that or not, rewrite rules as follows should get you most of the way there (assuming you have the capability):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: don't i have to map individual URL's to respected new URL's

Comment: i am not good at regex so if you can elaborate it a bit more ,that will be really helpful for me

Comment: If you're changing the URLs, yes, if you're keeping the permalink structure the same, no. For example: if you're moving from `http://oldsite.com/foo-bar/` to `http://www.newsite.com/foo-bar/`, you just need to do a regex remap for the base, but if you're moving to `http://www.newsite.com/bar-foo/`, you would need to remap individually.

Comment: @ m0r7if3r new site is duplicate of old one,everything same we are changing the domain name due to some unavoidable issues so what ever the structure of old site is will same in new one :)

Comment: Then either method above should work beautifully.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, though i am technically able to to it in .htaccess or other way, i was only doubtful about regular expression which are my long time enemies :)

Comment: Those ones are pretty basic, you should look at the regex for parsing shortcodes, it's a mess to read :D

Comment: i tried the above code in my .htaccess file but its not working as per my expectation. i have following URL on my localmachine `http://localhost/wordpress/2010/07/coming-home/` and its equivilant one on the server `http://www.mysite.com/wordpress/2010/07/coming-home/` but i am not getting redirected.Though for the home page `http://localhost/wordpress` redirection is working fine

Comment: why are you trying to redirect from localhost???

Comment: i have to actually do this redirection from old domain to new domain, so was testing how its working using my local-machine.